# Animate left position of an object with generated number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do we animate an object with an amount that I deduced with some calculations?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var someNumber = "'+='" + 500 + "'";
    $('.someClass').animate(
        {left:someNumber},
        {duration : 500, queue : false},
        function(){
        });
});
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/H7hpP/

Why is the element not animating?
P.S If I have to apply the same animation to two objects, is the following valid? I remember seeing it somewhere:

```
$('#firstPage #secondPage').animate(
{css property}, 
{duration},
function(){});
```

Beginners question, but that's what my experience with jQuery is.

Comment: there's an ' too much in '+='". also you must defines px, %, em, ... additionally, youre selecting an element that does not exist

Comment: @Alex: Corrected above things. Still missing something - http://jsfiddle.net/H7hpP/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) You dont need to add ' withing your string: `var someNumber = "+=" + 500 + "px";`
2.) You shall define what unit to animate, `px, em, %`
3.) Select an element that actually exists :)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7hpP/4/)

**Edit**

Just like in css, you can select several objects with `,`

```
$('#first, #second, #third').animate()
```

`$('#firstPage #secondPage')` would look for an element with id `secondPage` inside an element with id `firstPage`

Comment: Could you also point out about the secon part of the question i.e applying same animation to two objects?

Comment: oversaw that, one second my friend

Answer (score 0):

Please check out `jsfiddle.net/vinhnguyenle/H7hpP/8/`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.